# Custom header or query string when proxying request from Nginx to HHVM?

Tags: php, nginx, http-headers, hhvm

I'm using instructions in the following post as a guideline using Nginx as a proxy in front of HHVM: http://www.kyleboddy.com/2013/05/02/facebooks-hiphop-engine-when-to-use-it-and-getting-it-to-work-with-codeigniter/

Now something I have been able to do successfully in two different ways, is forwarding information as to the original URI, as follows:

```
location ~ .php$ {
        proxy_set_header Nginx-Uri $myuri;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8064/index.php?orig_uri=$myuri;
}
```

Now I can either access the custom header 'Nginx-Uri' using getallheaders(), or get the same information via $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].  But is one way preferable to the other?  I had some doubts as to whether HHVM would support [getallheaders()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php), due to it's formerly only being supported for PHP installed as an Apache module, whereas HHVM is it's own server, but HHVM does implement getallheaders() nevertheless, so that apparently is not a consideration.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both will work for the foreseeable future. getallheaders() should work on all transport methods, even once we implement fastcgi, modhhvm, or our own libevent server.

I personally dislike magic globals and prefer the function, but it is just personal preference. It could yield a perf improvement if we can analyze your code and see you never use a certain super global, we don't have to populate it.